# AVPlayer - Add Seconds to CMTime

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avplayer, cmtime

How can I add 5 seconds to my current playing Time?

Actually this is my code:

```
CMTime currentTime = music.currentTime;
```

I can´t use CMTimeGetSeconds() , because I need the CMTime format.

Thank you for your answers...

EDIT: How can I set a variable for CMTime?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(music.currentTime) + 5, music.currentTime.timescale);
```

Comment: When I replace the '+ 5' with '- 5' it is not working...Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: What is the current time in seconds? Perhaps the number goes negative?

Comment: This is my code: CMTime currentTime = music.currentTime;
    float currentTimeInt = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime);
    
    if (currentTimeInt > 5) {
        CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(music.currentTime) - 5, music.currentTime.timescale);
        [music seekToTime:newTime];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error");
        
    }

Comment: ...EDIT: Missed your if statement. Let me check again. Was it working with + 5 but not working with - 5?

Comment: The value doesn´t change whit the minus. I left the if statement out

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. You'll get an error in your log if currentTimeInt is less or equal to zero. You sure this is not the issue?

Comment: No, so what I mean is that if your currentTime is 5 seconds or less you will trigger your else block which spits out an error message in the log even though you don't actually have an error. The correct way would be to do the if statement without the else block.

Comment: Now the value changes :) but I can´t use it with seekToTime: (nothing happens when pressed). Do you know why?

Comment: Not from the top of my head. I suggest posting a new question for that. Good luck.

Answer (score 25):

elegant way is using `CMTimeAdd`

```
CMTime currentTime = music.currentTime;
CMTime timeToAdd   = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,1);

CMTime resultTime  = CMTimeAdd(currentTime,timeToAdd);

//then hopefully 
[music seekToTime:resultTime];
```

to your edit:
 you can create CMTime struct by these ways

```
CMTimeMake
CMTimeMakeFromDictionary
CMTimeMakeWithEpoch
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds
```

more @:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html

Comment: 'AVPlayer' may not respond to 'setCurrentTime'

Comment: Sending 'CMTime' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')

Comment: maybe you should use [music seekToTime: resultTime]

Answer (score 5):

In Swift:

```
private extension CMTime {

    func timeWithOffset(offset: TimeInterval) -> CMTime {

        let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self)
        let secondsWithOffset = seconds + offset

        return CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(secondsWithOffset, preferredTimescale: timescale)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4, using custom operator:

```
extension CMTime {
    static func + (lhs: CMTime, rhs: TimeInterval) -> CMTime {
        return CMTime(seconds: lhs.seconds + rhs,
                      preferredTimescale: lhs.timescale)
    }

    static func += (lhs: inout CMTime, rhs: TimeInterval) {
        lhs = CMTime(seconds: lhs.seconds + rhs,
                      preferredTimescale: lhs.timescale)
    }

}
```