# Swift Merge AVasset-Videos array

Tags: ios, arrays, video, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I want to merge the AVAsset-`arrayVideos` into one single video and save it on camera roll. Raywenderlich.com has a great [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift) where two videos are merged into one. I've created the following code, however the video that I get after exporting to camera roll includes only the first and the last video from the array (excluding the rest of the videos in the middle of `arrayVideos`). Am I missing something here?

```
var arrayVideos = [AVAsset]() //Videos Array    
var atTimeM: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
var lastAsset: AVAsset!
var layerInstructionsArray = [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
var completeTrackDuration: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
var videoSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

func mergeVideoArray(){

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    for videoAsset in arrayVideos{
        let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        do {
            if videoAsset == arrayVideos.first{
                atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
            } else{
                atTimeM = lastAsset!.duration
            }
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: atTimeM)  
            videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        completeTrackDuration = CMTimeAdd(completeTrackDuration, videoAsset.duration)
        let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        if videoAsset != arrayVideos.last{
            videoInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: videoAsset.duration)
        }
        layerInstructionsArray.append(videoInstruction)
        lastAsset = videoAsset            
    }

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, completeTrackDuration)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructionsArray        

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)

    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
    let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter!.outputURL = url as URL
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter!.videoComposition = mainComposition
    exporter!.exportAsynchronously {

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exporter!.outputURL!)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else{
                print("video erro: \(error)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to track the total time for all of the assets and update it for each video.

The code in your question was rewriting the `atTimeM` with the current video. That's why only the first and last got included.

It will look something like this:

```
...
var totalTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)

func mergeVideoArray() {

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    for videoAsset in arrayVideos {
        let videoTrack = 
            mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, 
                                           preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))          
        do {
            if videoAsset == arrayVideos.first {
                atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
            } else {
                atTimeM = totalTime // <-- Use the total time for all the videos seen so far.
            }
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), 
                                           of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], 
                                           at: atTimeM)  
            videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        totalTime += videoAsset.duration // <-- Update the total time for all videos.
...
```

You can remove the use of `lastAsset`.

Comment: Cheers Daniel. Just to complement your answer, we need to add the total time also in the following code:

if videoAsset != arrayVideos.last{
                videoInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: completeTrackDuration)
}

Comment: you can't increment totalTime with +=, you need to use CMTimeAdd.

Comment: don't use **totalTime += videoAsset.duration** use https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124487/4833705 instead

Comment: Don't forget to initialize totalTime or else it will be = NaN.  Make sure to put totalTime = CMTime.zero before running the loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

Use like

```
MeargeVide.mergeVideoArray(arrayVideos: arrayAsset) { (urlMeargeVide, error) in
 debugPrint("url",urlMeargeVide ?? "")
                debugPrint("error",error ?? "")
}
```

Complete class with orientation and merge multiple clip in single.

```
class MeargeVide {

   static func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform)
        -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
            var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
            var isPortrait = false
            if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                assetOrientation = .right
                isPortrait = true
            } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                assetOrientation = .left
                isPortrait = true
            } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
                assetOrientation = .up
            } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
                assetOrientation = .down
            }
            return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    static  func videoCompositionInstruction(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset)
        -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
            let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]

            let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
            let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)

            var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
            if assetInfo.isPortrait {
                scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
                let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
                instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor), at: kCMTimeZero)
            } else {
                let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
                var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
                    .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
                if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                    let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                    let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                    let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                    let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
                    concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
                }
                instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)
            }

            return instruction
    }

    class func mergeVideoArray(arrayVideos:[AVAsset], callBack:@escaping (_ urlGet:URL?,_ errorGet:Error?) -> Void){

        var atTimeM: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
        var lastAsset: AVAsset!
        var layerInstructionsArray = [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()
        var completeTrackDuration: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
        var videoSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        var totalTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.init()
        for videoAsset in arrayVideos{

            let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            do {
                if videoAsset == arrayVideos.first {
                    atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
                } else {
                    atTimeM = totalTime // <-- Use the total time for all the videos seen so far.
                }
                try videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration),
                                                of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0],
                                                at: completeTrackDuration)
                videoSize = (videoTrack?.naturalSize)!



            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }

            totalTime = CMTimeAdd(totalTime, videoAsset.duration)



            completeTrackDuration = CMTimeAdd(completeTrackDuration, videoAsset.duration)

            let firstInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstruction(videoTrack!, asset: videoAsset)
            firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: videoAsset.duration)

            layerInstructionsArray.append(firstInstruction)
            lastAsset = videoAsset
        }


        let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        mainInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructionsArray
        mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, completeTrackDuration)

        let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
        mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
        let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter!.outputURL = url as URL
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exporter!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exporter!.videoComposition = mainComposition
        exporter!.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                callBack(exporter?.outputURL, exporter?.error)
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: second video only displayed for one second and then the black screen displayed

Comment: for second video fix you'll need to set `firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: totalTime)`

Comment: this did not work for me... the second video is black and so is the third...

Comment: If you still see black screens, you need to setOpacity(0 at: totalTime).  You also need to make sure to initialize totalTime before running any loops (totalTime = CMTime.zero)

Comment: I got this thread [__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need atTimeM at all, since you are simply marching completeTrackDuration along it is where the next piece should be added.  So replace

```
if videoAsset == arrayVideos.first{
            atTimeM = kCMTimeZero
        } else{
            atTimeM = lastAsset!.duration
        }
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: atTimeM)
```

with

```
try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: completeTrackDuration)
```

Comment: this is not working - second video only displayed for one second and then the black screen displayed