# Combining two videos in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

So I have two .mp4s already recorded and stored in app, and I want to append one to the other, and export as a new video. It sort of works, but not quite!

```
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    var track = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID:Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: AAA as URL) as AVAsset
    let videoAsset2 = AVAsset(url: BBB as URL) as AVAsset
    do {
        try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset2.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

    } catch {
        print("darn")
    }

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = CCC
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true


    exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
        print("done?")
    }
```

This sort of combines the videos, but it adds massive chunks of black screen in between the two clips, and removes the audio. I cannot find any recent answers to this problem. Thanks for all help!

Comment: please add screenshot from ui

Comment: place the videos in an array and try this array merge https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972829/swift-merge-avasset-videos-array

Answer (score 1):

The video timeline looks wrong, e.g. you're inserting the both videos at the same point in time, zero, and using the wrong duration for `videoAsset2`.

The lack of audio is due to you not inserting any audio tracks into the composition.

Try something like this (repetitive) snippet:

```
// video
try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType:.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset2.duration), of: videoAsset2.tracks(withMediaType:.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: videoAsset.duration)

// audio
try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType:.audio)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
try track?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset2.duration), of: videoAsset2.tracks(withMediaType:.audio)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: videoAsset.duration)
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if it's good practice to use the `AVAssetTrack`'s owning `AVAsset` duration as a proxy for track length. Maybe you should be using `AVAssetTrack.timeRange`.